# Nitration of pyrrole with sulfuric and nitric acids

Tags: organic-chemistry, synthesis, aromatic-compounds, nitro-compounds, heterocyclic-compounds

Would 2,5-dinitropyrrole be a product of nitration of pyrrole with $\ce{H2SO4/HNO3}$? It seems that 2,5-dinitropyrrole is not formed when using $\ce{Ac2O/HNO3}$ (ref 1). Is this just because of the mild conditions used, or does this reflect the pyrrole ring being more deactivated by the first nitration than a benzene ring would be?

<sup>1</sup> Cooksey, A. R.; Morgan, K. J.; Morrey, D. P. Nitropyrroles—II : The nitration of pyrrole. *Tetrahedron* **1970,** *26* (21), 5101–5111. [DOI:10.1016/S0040-4020(01)93163-1](http://doi.org/10.1016/S0040-4020(01)93163-1)

Comment: Pyrrole is more activated towards electrophilic aromatic substitution, due to the electron donation of nitrogen atom.

Comment: Yes, but is 2-nitropyrrole activated towards electrophilic substitution relative to nitrobenzene? I assume it would be but then unfunctionalized dinitropyrroles should be relatively easy to make (unless the harsh conditions cause other side reactions). Sorry if I was being unclear !

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Would 2,5-dinitropyrrole be a product of nitration of pyrrole with $\ce{H2SO4/HNO3}$?

I doubt it and would rather expect a lot of tar to be formed here. Pyrrole tends to undergo acid-catalyzed polymerization!

For decades, acetyl nitrate, formed by addition of fuming nitric acid to acetic anhydride, is the reagent of choice.

Mononitration of pyrrole predominantly gives 2-nitropyrrole, accompanied by minor amounts of 3-nitropyrrole. (K.J. Morgan and D.P. Morrey, *Tetrahedron*, **1966**, *22*, 57–62. [DOI](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0040-4020(66)80101-1)).

In the case of 1-methylpyrrole, the yield of the 3-nitropyrole is somewhat larger (H.J. Anderson, *Canad. J. Chem*, **1957**, *35*, 23–29). In you want even more of the 3-nitro isomer, a more bulky alkyl substituent (*t-Bu*) or N-silylation with $\ce{((CH3)CH)2SiCl}$ is a viable approach.

Nitration of 2-nitropyrrole at −15 °C with nitric acid in acetic anhydride  furnishes a 4:1 mixture of 2,4- and 2,5-dinitropyrrole with a total yield of 61%. (R. Alan Jones, Gerritt P. Bean, *The Chemistry of Pyrroles: Organic Chemistry: A Series of Monographs*, Vol. 34, Academic Press, p. 124)

Comment: Safety concerns should be indicated here, particularly operating with concentrated nitric acid and any organic layers.