# Is synthesis of nitrobenzene possible without nitric and sulfuric acids?

Tags: organic-chemistry, aromatic-compounds, nitro-compounds, electrophilic-substitution

Is nitration of benzene possible without using the mixture of concentrated nitric and sulfuric acids $(\ce{HNO3}$ and $\ce{H2SO4})$?

Comment: related http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/29150/nitration-of-pyrrole

Answer (score 7):

It's getting on for 3 decades since since I've done organic, so a proper organic chemist can probably give a more complete answer, but yes, there are other ways to do this. In the $\ce{HNO3}$/$\ce{H2SO4}$ system the "real" nitrating agent is nitronium, $\ce{NO2+}$, so anything that can form that will nitrate benzene. One example is simply to use a nitronium salt such as nitronium tetrafluoroborate, $\ce{NO2+ BF4-}$. As for others I would be surprised to find that something like $\ce{NO2F}$/$\ce{BF3}$ doesn't work, but I don't know for certain - it's been a looooong time!

Comment: Acetyl nitrate, AcONO2, is also used - the reagent is pre-formed by reaction of nitric acid and acetic anhydride

Answer (score 2):

For some substrates, nitric acid plus nitrous acid works. In this system the generated electrophil is not $\ce{NO2^+}$, but $\ce{NO^+}$ formed from the nitrous acid accepting protons from the stronger nitric acid. If the substrate is sufficiently reactive, [as with the parent benzenoid compound benzene](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/93763/17175), then it can be attacked by the $\ce{NO^+}$. Then the nitroso group is oxidized by the nitric acid (regenerating the nitrous acid, which is thus acting as a catalyst).